# Apply jquery code on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

how can I apply a jquery function to elements that are loaded with ajax?

```
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
....
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.h').click(function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
</script>
```

So, this works perfectly. Every click on a span element returns an alert.
But there the click function is not applied to the elements loaded with ajax:

```
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
....
<span class="h">Test</span><br /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('body').append('<span class="h">Test3</span><br /><br />');
    }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.h').click(function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is what you'll want:

```
$('.h').live('click', function () {
  // Do something!
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And how can I use that on such a function:
    $('#element').externscript({ ... });

Comment: You drop that into your `$(document).ready(...);` in lieu of the original code you have there and put whatever click event code you need in place of the comment `// Do something!`

Comment: The alert above works perfectly. But now I want to apply that to a jquery extension called qtip -> http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/ So, I tried:

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element').live('mouseover', function() {
$(this).qtip();
});
});

But it does'nt work. My browser always crashes..

Comment: You'll need to do some more in-depth research on the specific plugin. Reference their API methods: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#methods

Comment: I can't see your point.. The plugin works for all elements that were not added by jquery's ajax function. So where is the problem?

Comment: Because I'm not the developer of qTip and can't say that their `.qtip()` method will be implemented using `.live()` or as simply binding to the `.mouseenter()` event.

Answer (score 0):

The `click()` function only adds a listener to the elements present at th time it was called. You need to call it again on any element, you add later on.

Or, as @jerluc stated, use the `live()` function.

Comment: Because, at the time, I didn't have a reference to the live function in the answer. So it was actually justified.

Comment: Your answer was still valid. `live()` is the most jQueryesque way of doing it - but there are other (quicker) methods of getting the same results. I think people should always leave comments when downvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use live instead of click, so that the event is binded also to newly appended items:

```
$('.h').live('click', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `live` function to bind the event to elements created dynamically:

```
$('.h').live('click', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reapplying the behaviour. You need to use jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to keep checking the DOM for new elements.

[Demonstration of live](http://jsfiddle.net/nJRpS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.h').live('click', function() {
            alert("test");
         });
     });
```