# Reapply jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

What is the best way to reapply functions in jquery? I do not want to use the live() function. An AJAX-request adds new items to my page and I want to make all of my jquery functions work on them.

How can I realign that jquery functions best, beside of live()?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give a code example...?

Comment: Just curious why  you don't want to use live?

Comment: From the comments in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580760/apply-jquery-code-on-all-elements), it appears as though you want to apply a plugin to your new elements. Is that right?

Comment: Well for things like ".dialog()", the ".live()" and ".delegate()" facilities are useless.  [This is the domain of a plugin I wrote.](http://gutfullofbeer.net/wallflower/doc/)

Comment: Yeah.. And it seems that it does not work with live()..

Comment: What do you mean by `"reapply functions"`? Use as event handlers for new content? Run a function that affects the new content?

Comment: @wendel: What is a jQuery function for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really dont want to use live(), you can just run the jquery again after the items are added to the page in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate(). look [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for documentation

Comment: I like ".delegate()" too, but it won't work for things like jQuery UI setup etc.